# CSS3 Media Queries Not Being Picked Up

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm just getting into media queries, but this first issue is driving me crazy I've spent hours on it.

I've tried to following:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    div.logothingy {
        z-index: 100;
        display:none !important;
    }
}
@media (max-device-width: 480px) {
    div.logothingy {
        z-index: 100;
        display:none !important;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    div.logothingy {
        z-index: 100;
        display:none !important;
    }
}
```

I load it at the end of my head file and when i look at it in firebug it's there.

Then I go to an object .logothingy and it is not even getting the styling when i reduce my window size down small. That is to say it's not even getting it and then being overwritten, it's just not getting it at all. Going insane. Please help.

Ok I'm even doing this:

```
.logothingy {
border:1px solid;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
.logothingy {
z-index: 100;
display:none !important;
}
}
```

and it's putting the border and not doing the rest of it.
I have this in the head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Update2: I changed it to 780px and it works, but when it's at 480px it can shrink all the way down to nothing without getting the styling.

Comment: why are you saying display none and changing the z-index to 100?

Comment: Your code seems fine, perhaps there is other code overwriting it somewhere else. Here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/neilheinrich/LBUYW/. Remember that "max-width" is going to be the size of the iframe in the result window on jsfiddle, not the entire browser window.

Comment: I'm putting that styling in so I can make sure it works. There is no code overwriting it, because it should still show up as overridden in firebug.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same dramas and noticed that i had missed this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

in the head of my index page. Added it and media queries all kicked in.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct one

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
}
```

Try to put inside only .logothingy instead of div.logothingy and let us know if worked

Comment: I tried how you suggested and it still didn't work. Before this I was even trying #logo which is it's ID, but that wasn't being picked up either. I just also tried commenting out all other stylesheets and it still is not working.

Comment: I also just tried putting a regular style before the media query and it worked fine.

Comment: im used to always put in the media query ids or general elemnts, never tried with classes, but it should work. I was today like half hour trying to figure out why the media query wasnt working and resulted at the end that I had a { the line before the @media started, sometimes you get blind (at least me) to the most silly errors, if your media query is correct, the error should be in other place